# Is there a what to simplify this statement?

Tags: mysql

It wouldn't surprise me if there were already an answer to this type of problem, but I don't know how to ask it.

The statement compares the task keys in the task table against the task/tag key combinations in another table.

I use PHP to execute this SQL, which compares values in one table against the values of another table. It works perfectly, but it looks ridiculously inefficient. It uses the same inner select statement three times to compare against a single value each time.

```
SELECT * FROM ttasks t
WHERE bComplete = 0
  AND ( 1 IN (SELECT iTagKey FROM ttagties WHERE t.taskKey = iLinkKey AND iType = 0)
        OR 3 IN (SELECT iTagKey FROM ttagties WHERE t.taskKey = iLinkKey AND iType = 0) )
  AND 10 NOT IN (SELECT iTagKey FROM ttagties WHERE t.taskKey = iLinkKey AND iType = 0)
ORDER BY dCreated;
```

Is there something like:

```
WHERE bComplete = 0
  AND ((1 OR 3) AND NOT 10) IN (SELECT iTagKey FROM ttagties WHERE t.taskKey = iLinkKey AND iType = 0)
```

or maybe

```
WHERE bComplete = 0
  AND ASSIGN SET AS (SELECT iTagKey FROM ttagties WHERE t.taskKey = iLinkKey AND iType = 0)
  AND (1 IN (SET) OR 3 IN (SET)) AND 10 NOT IN (SET)
```

Even if you can't find a better way of writing the statement, could you suggest some better ways to describe the problem?

To clarify, the SELECT in the parentheses could be a set like (1,5,6,10). I haven't found a JOIN that rejects the set because it has a 10, even though it also has a 1.

Here is the complete dataset for table `ttagties`:

```
CREATE TABLE ttagties (
  iLinkKey INT,
  iTagKey INT,
  iType INT);

INSERT INTO ttagties VALUES
(1,3,0),(2,1,0),(2,10,0),(3,10,0),(4,1,0),(4,10,0),(7,1,0),(7,10,0),(8,1,0),
(8,5,0),(8,10,0),(11,1,0),(11,10,0),(14,1,0),(14,10,0),(19,3,0),(19,10,0),
(21,3,0),(21,10,0),(23,3,0),(23,10,0),(25,3,0),(28,2,0),(29,2,0),(30,1,0),
(30,10,0),(31,2,0),(32,1,0),(32,6,0),(32,10,0),(33,1,0),(33,10,0),(34,2,0),
(34,6,0),(35,2,0),(36,3,0),(37,3,0),(38,1,0),(38,10,0),(39,2,0),(48,3,0),
(48,10,0),(51,1,0),(51,5,0),(51,7,0),(51,10,0),(54,1,0),(54,10,0),(55,2,0),
(57,10,0),(58,3,0),(58,10,0),(58,11,0),(60,1,0),(60,5,0),(60,10,0),(67,2,0),
(68,2,0),(69,10,0),(70,10,0),(71,2,0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join to the tag table *twice*; once to find a hit on 1 or 3 and again to assert there is *no* hit on 10:

```sql
select distinct t.* 
from ttasks t 
join ttagties tt on t.taskKey = tt.iLinkKey
  and tt.iTagKey IN (1,3)
  and tt.iType=0
left join ttagties tt2 on t.taskKey = tt2.iLinkKey
  and tt2.iTagKey = 10
  and tt2.iType=0
where t.bComplete = 0
and tt2.iLinkKey is null
order by t.dCreated
```

Using `distinct` removes duplicates in case there are multiple hits on 1, 3.

The check for `null` asserts that the join to 10 tagkeys failed to find any.

---

This can be simplified *somewhat*, probably at the cost of performance, as follows:

```
with tags as (
    select iLinkKey, iTagKey
    from ttagties where iTagKey IN (1,3,10)
    where iType = 0
)
select distinct t.*
from ttasks t 
join tags tt on t.taskKey = tt.iLinkKey
  and iTagKey != 10
left join tags tt2 on t.taskKey = tt2.iLinkKey
  and tt2.iTagKey = 10
where t.bComplete = 0
and tt2.iLinkKey is null
order by t.dCreated
```

but the style gain, if any, is marginal.

Comment: This works beautifully, and I love that it uses 'distinct' and joins instead of sub-queries (is that the correct phrase?). I will have to study to figure out WHY it works. I didn't know you could put 'and's with join statements. That's a game-changer.

Comment: @bookworm cool. I've added some more comments to explain. Note that putting non-key conditions in a join condition may improve performance and definitely improves readability (it puts all the stuff related to a join in one place), but it is essential with outer joins; putting such conditions in the `where` clause effectively forces the outer join to be an inner join. This pattern of using left join with extra conditions then check for null is a handy arrow to have in your quiver when you need to check for *absence* of certain child rows. It also only returns 1 row, so you may not need distinct

Answer (score 2):

You could use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` to re-write your query

```
SELECT * 
FROM ttasks t 
WHERE t.bComplete = 0
  AND EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 
     FROM ttagties t1 
     WHERE t.taskKey = t1.iLinkKey AND t1.iType = 0 AND t1.iTagKey IN (1,3)) 
  AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 
     FROM ttagties t2 
     WHERE t.taskKey = t2.iLinkKey AND t2.iType = 0 AND t2.iTagKey = 10) 
ORDER BY t.dCreated;
```

Comment: You're missing `AND` in between `WHERE t.bComplete = 0  EXISTS ...`

Comment: This works and is an improvement! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `JOIN`, `GROUP_CONCAT()`, `HAVING` and `FIND_IN_SET()` functions could be an alternative:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t.taskKey, t.bComplete, t.dCreated, GROUP_CONCAT(iTagKey) AS iTagKeys
  FROM ttasks t 
  JOIN ttagties tt ON t.taskKey = tt.iLinkKey 
WHERE t.bComplete = 0
  AND tt.iType=0
GROUP BY t.taskKey, t.bComplete, t.dCreated
ORDER BY t.dCreated) 
  
SELECT taskKey, bComplete, dCreated
  FROM cte
WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(1,iTagKeys) OR FIND_IN_SET(3,iTagKeys))
  AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(10,iTagKeys);
```

Or maybe like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t.taskKey, t.bComplete, t.dCreated, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN iTagKey IN (1,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS iTagKeys
  FROM ttasks t 
  JOIN ttagties tt ON t.taskKey = tt.iLinkKey 
WHERE t.bComplete = 0
  AND tt.iType=0
GROUP BY t.taskKey, t.bComplete, t.dCreated) 
  
SELECT taskKey, bComplete, dCreated
  FROM cte
WHERE iTagKeys=1
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/setW0ZW_)

Comment: Post the data sample that you use to run against using you own query and the one I suggested.

Comment: I've did test it in the fiddle with some sample data I've conjured up myself and both queries return the same result. Here, you can use this fiddle as well to input your sample data https://dbfiddle.uk/-_4ExsQX

Comment: I posted my actual data to the original question.

Comment: How about data from table `ttask`?

Comment: Ah ok.. I see what you mean now

Comment: You're new response works and is instructive. Thank you!